# Remove prepended commits from previous git branch

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, branching-and-merging

Working on a project we messed up the syncing while changing between branches. At first there was one feature branch `foo`, this got rebased to master, however, locally master was not synced, so when moved to a new branch, `bar`, all the commits from the previous one were prepended to new branch as well. The git tree looks something like this:

```
Master =>  A--B--C--D--E--Merge
               \-C--D--E-/-F--G--H   <= Bar
                  Foo
```

My goal is to remove `foo` completely, since it is already rebased to master, and have something like:

```
Master =>  A--B--C--D--E
                        \-F--G--H    <=Bar
```

EDIT:

So it seems that this is more messy then I taught. Also, I am not that versed in git, and cannot conclude what exactly even happened. I'll go now in as much detail as I can.

Teammate and I are working on a project. To implement one feature, we created a separate branch `foo`.

```
A -- B <-- (master)
      \
       C -- D -- E <-- (foo)
```

After finishing the feature, I rebased the `foo` to `master`. And the tree now looked like this:

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- E <-- (master)
```

New feature needed to be implemented, and thus new branch `bar` opened.

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- E <-- (master)
                     \
                      F -- G -- H <-- (bar)
```

This was all on my end. Now the teammate pushed his code, and I presume he didn't have some branches synced, and additionally had some conflicts that needed merging, but in the end, the git tree looks like this:

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- E <-- (master)
      \             | \
       C -- D -------- M1 ------ M2 -- I <-- (bar)
                    \           /
                     F -- G -- H
```

Where:

- M1 stated: merge `master` into `foo`
- M2 stated: merge `bar` into `foo`
- `I` is new teammate's commit

Additionally, I am a bit confused by the message in M2, since it then means that we are left with `foo` in the end, but our tree only has `bar`.

I did try, as @Mark Adelsberger suggested, running `git rebase master bar`, but I immediately got merge conflicts on commit `C`, and I aborted the rebase. As per answer, it should automatically decide that those both `C`s are the same commit, and skip them, but this was not the case.

My goal is to flatten the tree if possible, meaning, getting rid of `C` and `D` in `bar` branch, and hopefully merging or putting `F`, `G` and `H` in the same line as `M1`, `M2` and `I`.

Going back to the issue, I see that my first post lacked quite a bit of detail. Hopefully this edit will clarify the problem which I'm facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, although @Mark Adelsberger's answer didn't exactly solve it, it did show me a direction to look into.

Doing a simple `git rebase master bar` didn't do it, since I run into conflicts on commit `C` immediately. This should have not happened since the commit is a duplicate, and should have been skipped.

However, doing `git rebase -i master bar` did help, because I could manually exclude the commits `C` and `D`. On top of that, it also got rid of `M1` and `M2`, making a nice and clean log.